# Expandable ListView with section header

Tags: android, header, xamarin.android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to create an Expandable list view with section headers. I attempted two example methods of the the following example,

- Merge Expandable Example by CommonsWare (http://bit.ly/gm6roZ)
- Separating Lists with Headers by Jeff Sharkey (http://bit.ly/1ayuTq)

I managed to get these to work using listView, however, when I switch into using expandableListView, I have encountered few issues:

[image]

1. As I attempt to implement Jeff's method, it seems the headers happen to have an indicator and clickable. When I think about it, this does not seem right. the headers should not be an expandableListView, or at least not suppose to behave like one.
2. I have also noticed that I do no longer have a function for IsEnabled() when implementing for custom expandableListAdapter. this might be the reason on my headers are being enabled as a expandablelistview. I've considered that I might have been replaced by IsChildSelectable() but it is not what I need (which is enable/disable group list).

I did asked someone in IRC channel and they've told me that it could be that I might missing few steps on the wrapping part, but I can't be sure of that, so Ill throw the code for the time being.

(btw, I'm using Xamarin's monodroid. but the style and flow more or less the same as android, so I understand android's code aswell, so here it is )

**SeparatedExpandableAdapter class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Object = Java.Lang.Object;

namespace AndroidApplication10
{
    class SeparatedExpandableListAdapter :BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {
        public readonly Context context;
        public readonly Dictionary<string, IExpandableListAdapter> sections = new Dictionary<string, IExpandableListAdapter>();
        public readonly ArrayAdapter<string> headers;
        public static readonly int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;

        public SeparatedExpandableListAdapter(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            headers = new ArrayAdapter<string>(context, Resource.Layout.list_header, Resource.Id.list_header_title);
        }

        //register our adapter with a section.
        public void AddSection(string section, IExpandableListAdapter adapter)
        {
            headers.Add(section);
            sections.Add(section, adapter);
        }

        /*
         * Algorithm for separatedList
         *      ::correctly find the selected item among child adapters::
         *          - subtract from the original position
         *          - do logic once the position find the header (position == 0)
         *          - do logic once the position find the adapter (position < size)
         */

        public override Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
        {
            foreach (var section in sections)
            {
                var size = section.Value.GroupCount + 1;
                if (groupPosition == 0) return section.Key;
                if (groupPosition < size) return section.Value.GetGroup(groupPosition - 1);

                groupPosition -= size;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public override Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            foreach (var section in sections)
            {
                var size = section.Value.GroupCount + 1;
                if (groupPosition == 0) return null;
                if (groupPosition < size) return section.Value.GetChild(groupPosition - 1, childPosition);

                groupPosition -= size;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public override int GroupCount
        {
            get
            {
                var total = 0;
                foreach (var adapter in sections.Values)
                {
                    total += adapter.GroupCount + 1;
                }
                return total;
            }
        }
        public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
        {
            foreach (var section in sections)
            {
                var size = section.Value.GroupCount + 1;
                if (groupPosition == 0) return 0;
                if (groupPosition < size) return section.Value.GetChildrenCount(groupPosition - 1);

                groupPosition -= size;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        public override bool IsEmpty
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override int GroupTypeCount
        {
            get
            {
                var total = 1;
                foreach (var adapter in sections.Values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[ROXEZ]: GroupTypeCount? " + ((BaseExpandableListAdapter)adapter).GroupTypeCount);
                    total += ((BaseExpandableListAdapter) adapter).GroupTypeCount; //?
                    Console.WriteLine("[ROXEZ]: total? " + total);
                }
                return total;
            }
        }
        public override int ChildTypeCount
        {
            get
            {
                return base.ChildTypeCount;
            }
        }

        public override int GetGroupType(int groupPosition)
        {
            var type = 1;
            foreach (var section in sections)
            {
                var size = section.Value.GroupCount + 1;
                if (groupPosition == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
                if (groupPosition < size)
                    return ((BaseExpandableListAdapter) (section.Value)).GetGroupType(groupPosition);
                groupPosition -= size;
                type += ((BaseExpandableListAdapter) (section.Value)).GroupTypeCount;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        public override int GetChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return base.GetChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);
        }

        public override bool AreAllItemsEnabled()
        {
            return false;
        }
        public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Position: " + groupPosition + " | Output: " + (GetGroupType(groupPosition) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER));
                return (GetGroupType (groupPosition) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);
        }

        public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            var sectionNum = 0;
            foreach (var section in sections)
            {
                var size = section.Value.GroupCount + 1;
                if (groupPosition == 0)
                {
                    return headers.GetView(groupPosition, convertView, parent);
                }
                if (groupPosition < size) return section.Value.GetGroupView(groupPosition - 1, isExpanded, convertView, parent);

                groupPosition -= size;
                sectionNum++;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var sectionNum = 0;
            foreach (var section in sections)
            {
                var size = section.Value.GroupCount + 1;
                if (groupPosition == 0) return null;
                if (groupPosition < size) return section.Value.GetChildView(groupPosition - 1, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);

                groupPosition -= size;
                sectionNum++;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
        {
            return groupPosition;
        }
        public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return childPosition;
        }


        public override bool HasStableIds
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
}
```